# Is HTML5 localStorage safe long term?

Tags: html, local-storage

I am learning HTML, Javascript, etc., and decided to make a small web app on the Chrome Web Store as an educational project.  The app stores a few bits of important data in localStorage (essentially small saved text files), and I was wondering if this implementation choice is too fragile.  I know that the user will lose data if their hard drive dies or they manually delete it, but is the data in danger under normal circumstances?  For example, does Chrome ever decide to clean out localStorage for maintenance reasons?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, Chrome deletes everything - including local storage - when you select "Clear Browsing Data", which some users might do if they're told to do something like "empty your browser's cache" without realising the implications.

The HTML5 spec doesn't specify anything with regards to the safety of data, possibly because it's a very young draft. I'd play it on the safe side and store that data in the cloud as well - it's what your users expect.

Comment: I'd say that users expect their data to be stored.. but not necessarily in the cloud. :)

Comment: They expect it to be stored permanently unless they expressly delete it. Considering how easy it is to accidentally delete your local storage data, remote + local is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Morgan: Yes, and I'm saying that Remote doesn't have to be "The Cloud".. It can simply be the database on your web server.

Comment: ... yeah, that is "the cloud". "The cloud" is "remote storage", database on web server included.

Comment: @Morgan: [Not quite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Cloud_storage).. You're using the term far too loosely.

Comment: "The cloud" as in the first definition of cloud computing, not cloud storage which is a different thing entirely. Personally I try to avoid word precisely because it is so poorly defined, but I occasionally find myself dropping it into conversation by accident.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest treating local and session storage as you would cookies. Helpful if it's there but not vital, and you can carry on without it (and possibly recreate it and store it again).